# Error while Adding value onto a dictionary in python loop

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to parse a Json structure in python and Adding a new value with key 'cat':

```
data = []

for x in a:
    for y in x['Hp'].values():
        for z in y:
            for k in z['abc']['xyz']:
                for m in data:
                    det = m['response']
                    // Some processing with det whose output is stored in s 
                    k['cat'] = s
    print x
```

However when x is print only the last value is being appended onto the whole dictionary, wheras there are different values for s.
Its obvious that the 'cat' key is being overwritten everytime the loop rounds,but can't find a way to make it right

Below is a sample Json structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asdasda156121s"),
    "Hp" : {
        "bermud" : [ 
            {
                "abc" : {
                    "gfh" : 1,
                    "fgh" : 0.0,
                    "xyz" : [ 
                        {
                            "kjl" : "0",
                            "bnv" : 0,
                        }
                    ],
                    "xvc" : "bv",
                    "hgth" : "INnn",
                    "sdf" : 0,
                    }
                }
            },
           {
                "abc" : {
                    "gfh" : 1,
                    "fgh" : 0.0,
                    "xyz" : [ 
                        {
                            "kjl" : "0",
                            "bnv" : 0,
                        }
                    ],
                    "xvc" : "bv",
                    "hgth" : "INnn",
                    "sdf" : 0,
                    }
                }
            },
            ..
```

Comment: what is `a, x, y`? Is it a list? If `z` is dictionary, then `k` is list element or what?

Comment: provide your JSON or example

Comment: x and j are dicts, k is a list element.

Comment: @radix What are their values?

Comment: So many loops so confusing to look at, is there anyway to simplify your looping

Comment: Could you add how `a` looks like in your question?

Comment: added a sample json

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store all values change

```
k['cat'] = s
```

to

```
if 'cat' in k.keys():
    k['cat'] += s
else:
    k['cat'] = s
```

If you want to store only the first one change

```
k['cat'] = s
```

to

```
if 'cat' not in k.keys():
    k['cat'] = s
```

Comment: cat is being added as 'abcde' instead of just a

Comment: I edited my solution to store only the first value.